# Remove a word and an associated comma and/or spaces from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am given two strings:

```
s1 = "abc, bcd, abc xyz, abc pq"
s2 = "abc"
```

I wish to construct a third string that equals `s1` with the first occurrence of `s2` removed. In addition, if that occurence in `s1` is followed by spaces or by a comma and then spaces, those characters are to be removed as well. Lastly, if that occurrence is at the end of `s1`, the spaces preceding that occurrence are to be removed.

In the example above I wish to produce the string

```
"bcd, abc xyz, abc pq"
```

Two more examples:

```
s2 = "xyz" should produce "abc, bcd, abc abc pq"
s2 = "pq"  should produce "bcd, abc xyz, abc"
```

You may assume that if `s1` contains `s2`, that part of the string will not be immediately preceded or followed by characters other than a comma or space. For example, you don't have to worry about cases such as

```
s1 = "abc, bedbug, bed"
s2 = "bed"
```

Comment: So what have you done to try and accomplish this yourself? We're not here to do your job for you. You write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: In what data structure is your list stored?

Comment: Its a string. @MarcB Be Gentle. I am not your goat. abc,|,abc

Comment: A regular expression for this task is massive overkill.

Comment: What u suggest tadman.

Comment: @NooB8374 The golden rule here is showing **what you've tried**. Without any demonstration of effort it looks like you're trying to score free programming.

Comment: @tadman, I believe the SO rule here is that, for homework problems, askers are to explain what efforts they've made to solve the problem  (but not necessarily provide code). Aside from that, should readers care how much effort they've made to solve the problem, if they question is interesting and/or other readers, as well as the asker, might benefit from a solution?

Comment: Homework questions are a touchy subject, but the important criteria is that effort toward solving the problem exists. If no such effort is in evidence, then we're obligated, because of our place in a user-supported community, to point out how to ask, and then, possibly if we feel like it, provide suggestions and pointers toward a solution. We shouldn't ever spoon feed someone because we might have to work with them some day. Reiterating or rewording the instructions they were given doesn't constitute effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma separated lists can be deconstructed and reconstructed easily:

```
list = "abc, bcd, abc xyz, abc pq"
list.split(/,\s+/).join(', ')
```

This means you can delete unwanted elements in the middle:

```
parts = list.split(/,\s+/)
parts.delete('abc')
parts.join(', ')
# => "bcd, abc xyz, abc pq"
```

A regular expression to do the substitution makes for a lot more work here, but you'll notice I used one to do the separation.